# Where is "pejorative" pronounced " ˈpejəˌrātiv"?

Tags: pronunciation

Upon looking up the word *pejorative*, I noticed two rather distinct pronunciations:

> pəˈjôrətiv
>   ˈpejəˌrātiv

I naturally assumed the first (which is apparently the more common), but was wondering in what parts of the world the second pronunciation is commonly used.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You already seem to know how it's pronounced, so are you just surveying the crowd to see which individual people use?

Comment: Yes, more of a survey... being that titles can't have bold/italics, it was hard to ask "How do **you** pronounce 'pejorative'?"

Comment: @snumpy Survey questions are the bane of the StackExchange network, because every answer is equally valid...what happens is you get a thread like, "I say pejorative like XX"; "No, I say perjorative like YY!, and it just becomes a mess, particularly because people don't know when to stop past the point of usefulness.  I'd advise you to modify your question a bit so it doesn't get closed...

Comment: Still looking for anyone who can clarify where it's pronounced `ˈpejəˌrātiv`

Comment: @snumpy: I'm with you there, mate. You're obviously *not* inviting everyone to start arguing about the 'correct' pronunciation. You're effectively asking whether *anyone* actually uses the second. And if so, where do they come from, with a view to establishing if the variation might be geographical.

Comment: @snumpy It's mostly an accident, its one of the ways you might pronounce if if you've read it but not heard it. I've heard two people stress the pej the first few times they say it, others skipped the a and said something like perjortive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly.  Thank you for clarifying my ramblings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, well clarified. @Snumpy, the new title is definitely better. @TobyLane, while I agree with you that that does happen, I don't think it would make its way into the dictionary that way. There must be a dialect where this pronunciation is common. Now, all that remains is to find it... ummm....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it may be be more of a question of when it was pronounced thus than where. Bryan Garner has this on the word:

> Though once pronounced /**pee**-jər-ay-tiv/ (or, in BrE, /**pee**-jər-ə-tiv/), the predominant (and fully acceptable) pronunciation today is /pə-**jor**-ə-tiv/.

<sup>*Garner's Modern American Usage*</sup>

My guess is that the earlier pronunciations were holdovers from the much older, but [now rare](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=pejorate&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), **pejorate**, /**pee**-jər-ayt/, (make worse, cause to deteriorate).

Comment: Now that's helpful! If I don't see anything better over the next few days, the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 1):

This pair is similar to the two ways of pronouncing *territory*: /təɹɪtoɹi/ and /təɹɪt(ʃ)ɹi/ where the unaccented o reduces to a schwa or is elided.

In dialects where people accentuate the /o/ in *pejorative*, the pronunciation will be like the first, whereas dialects which accentuate the first /e/ in pejorative will pronounce it the second way. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the features of different dialects and where they are spoken. Perhaps somebody else can help here.

I speak a dialect of English that accents the /o/ in *territory* and *pejorative*.

Comment: For what it's worth, I elide the *o* in *territory*, but I accent the *o* in *pejorative* (and this is common in the UK). So while the idea may be the same, there isn't a correlation between the two words :)

Comment: Agree with @psmears.

Comment: And those who might stress the first syllable, would they pronounce the a long? The recessive accent often causes all subsequent syllables to become a mumble, as with TERritry. Placing secondary stress on the a and stretching it sounds a bit Southern US to me?

Comment: @Cerberus while I agree that drawling out syllables unnecessarily is quite indicative of the Southeastern US, I'm from Georgia and have never heard it pronounced like that (granted, the majority of people who might pronounce it that way would likely not know its meaning).

Comment: @snumpy: Haha, fair enough. Well, it was only speculation; I think I know only peJOrative.

Comment: @psmears I said they were *similar*, not *correlated*.

Comment: @Cerberus Tennesseans and Virginians don't pronounce it like that either. From what I've heard, "pejorative" pronounced with a (strong) Southern accent comes out something like "p(uh)-JOOR-(uh)-t(ee)ive," where the stuff in parentheses are optional. One of these days, I need to learn to type in IPA...

Comment: @Peter Yep - I wasn't suggesting that you did say that, merely adding another data point (partly because otherwise some people reading might jump to that conclusion, despite you not having said it :)

Comment: @kitukwyer: Right, well that makes sense. Our quest is still for anyone stressing the first syllable, then; tally-ho, oh, no wait...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any historical, regional or dialectal associations for the second pronunciation, though I can't rule them out.

But I do think many could conciously or unconciously associate it with the word **perjury**.

The misspelling *perjorative* isn't uncommon, and I suspect this too might be influenced by phonetic proximity to the other word sharing some semantic territory in the general area of *bad stuff, socially speaking*.

Answer (score -1):

France maybe. I know that it sounds very french when spoken that way.

Comment: Does France have a native English-speaking population?  I would expect dictionaries to account for primary dialects, not foreign accents (or else there would be 100 pronunciations for each word).

Comment: The French would have a hard '**f**' at the end for this particular word, but it's still four syllables. My gut feel is they don't mind the leading stress on long words so much. We on the other hand tend to move the stress further down as a word grows from, say *detonate* to *detonation*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. It's a novelty to be told why you are wrong in a constructive manner.

Comment: Well that bit about (Brits, at least) not liking the main stress on the first syllable in long words is entirely my own 'armchair philosophising', so it might not even be true. Maybe someone more knowledgeable will either confirm or squash the idea.